# Share Azure DevOps agent between classic deployment group and yaml environment

Tags: azure-devops

We have Azure Devops agents in Deployment Groups and would like to start migrating to YAML pipelines. This means registering agents in Environments.

Is there some way a Deployment Group and Environment can share the same agent? Or am I forced to install two agents to support both classic and YAML pipelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below steps to share agents in environment to deployment pool. There is a mapping between environment and deployment pool.

1 add resource virtual machine to an environment
[image: add vm to an environment]

2 after registering resource successfully, you’ll see an env pool added automatically
[image: env pool]

3 select a project to share
[image: select project]

Note: please create environment first because it’s one-way mapping.